# android custom actionbar using?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm newbie in android please help me. I created a class that contains my actionbar code i want to use it in all activies. how can i run/call it in my activities?
Thank You.

**ActionBar Class :**

```
public class CustomActionBar extends Activity {

        public void actionbarMethod() {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View actionBarView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);

            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
            actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
            actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarView, new ActionBar.LayoutParams
                    (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            final DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ImageView btnmenu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnmenu);

            btnmenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                    } else {
                        drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);

                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

** ActionBar XML Layout :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="#36abcb" >


<ImageView
android:id="@+id/btnmenu"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:padding="8dip"
android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer"
android:background="#36abcb"/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/title"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnmenu"
android:textSize="18dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make all your activities subclasses of CustomActionBar.

ETA: they also need to call actionbarMethod() in their onCreate()

```
public class MyActivity extends CustomActionBar {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myactivityview);
        actionbarMethod();
        // ... more code
    }

}
```

Comment: tanx. it worked fine but when i click on menu button in main activity it works but in other activities it crashes.How can i fix it?

Comment: You need to move the menu functions from your main activity to CustomActionBar.

Comment: I defined the menu button and its click listener in CustomActionBar  activity but it still crashes

Comment: @vahidhasani You need `@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` and sometimes also onPrepareOptionsMenu

Comment: would you please explain more specific ? I don't have  onPrepareOptionsMenu at all .!

Comment: here is a [tutorial](http://www.101apps.co.za/articles/using-menus-in-your-apps-a-tutorial.html)